# Optimal solution for storing card values in a multiplayer card game

Tags: java, multiplayer

I am developing multiplayer turn based card game([Mendikot](https://www.pagat.com/pointtrk/mendikot.html))

in JAVA.There are four players in two teams, partners sitting opposite
A standard international 52-card pack is used. The cards of each suit rank from high to low A-K-Q-J-10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2.
Each player gets random 13 card each.

Now I have two ways to store this data,one is to store the data using data structure as below.

```
private static String[] suits = { "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};

private static String[] ranks = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
```

and then store each combination of "suits and ranks" for each of the four players in a separate list and then update the list after each turn to remove played card.

Secondly I can go a database solution with table like "Players","Card","Moves" etc.
where in the "Moves" tables will store cards own by each player.Which can be cleared after the game is over

I am considering this Portal as multithreaded as many players can form different rooms to play.

Please suggest me the optimal way to store the data considering the concurrent nature of the portal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's mostly a OOP modelling exercise and might be more appreciated on codereview.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is an example of [stringly typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped): Using strings when more specific data-types would be more appropriate.

In this case I would recommend you to use [enumerations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for both suits and ranks. A card should be a class with two public variables, `Rank rank` and `Suit suit`. A card doesn't change its rank or suit, so this should be an immutable class. You can do that with the `final` keyword.

```
public enum Suit {
     HEARTHS,
     SPADES,
     DIAMONDS,
     CLUBS  
}

public enum Rank {
     TWO,         
     THREE,       
     FOUR,       
     FIVE,       
     SIX,       
     SEVEN,       
     EIGHT,       
     NINE,       
     TEN,     
     JACK,
     QUEEN,
     KING,
     ACE
}

public class Card {
     public final Suit suit;
     public final Rank rank;

     public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
          this.suit = suit;
          this.rank = rank;
     }
}
```

Why should you do this instead of just using strings? Take this code, for example:

```
player.giveCard("ACE", "SPADE");
```

There might be not one but two bugs in that tiny line of code which are undetectable by the compiler and will only appear at runtime. Can you spot them?

> It should be "SPADES", not "SPADE", and it might be the other way around, suit first, rank second.

Now take this code:

```
player.giveCard(new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.SPADE));
```

In this case, both bugs will be caught by the java compiler. It will tell you that `Suit.SPADE` doesn't exist and that the types don't match the signature of the constructor of Card (the first parameter needs to be of type `Suit` and the second of type `Rank`).

Comment: Thanks Phillipp... But what I want is whether storing the records in DB will be efficient or using your suggested method.I have to store diff instances of the game(diff game room) with updating the game data after every turn.So which one will be efficient for N nos of playing rooms?

Comment: @Amiz There is no one solution for that. Keeping the gamestate in memory will result in simpler Java code (no persistence layer required) and less time wasted with waiting for database responses (which means a more fluid game experience), but it requires more RAM. A turn-based game is an edge-case where both solutions can make sense. So this is a tradeoff you need to decide for yourself. Personally I generally try the simpler "good enough" solution first, but keep a possible switch to the more complicated solution in mind while designing my architecture.